# problema flutter

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

hola buenas espero estén bien... tengo un problema ... ya instale los plugins de flutter y de dart en Android Studio ... ya instale todo pero no mas y no puedo..

[image: introducir la descr]

en la imagen me dice todo eso pero ya esta configurado todo eso ... pero no logro que me salgan todas las palomitas si me pudieran ayudar se los agradecería :)

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! ahi dice que no.... estas seguro?

Answer (score 1):

Con respecto a el mensaje:

> "Unable to locate Android SDK"

que es el problema principal, debes conocer donde lo instalaste e ir a `File` > `Project Structure` > `SDK Location`, ahí definir la ruta del SDK.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: hehe si bro... ya pude ... tuve que hacer variables de entorno... pero gracias :D

Answer (score 0):

Agrega el sdk de flutter a las variables de entorno, si aun sigues teniendo problemas con android instala un sdk anterior por alguna razón eso resolvio el problema con el mio. Suerte